# How many possible bit strings of length 12 is the number of 1s an integer multiple of the number of 0s?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Question:In how many possible bit strings of length 12 is the number of 1s an integer multiple of the number of 0s?

Can someone please show the solution since on there is no solution on the textbook? I don't understand since there" an integer multiple". Is it like 2,4,8,...?

Comment: Let $x$ be the number of 0s. Then $12-x$ is the number of 1s. They want the cases where there exists an integer $n$ such that $12-x = nx$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add up the following:

- The number of strings with $ 1$ zero  and $11$ ones is $\dbinom{12}{ 1}= 12$
- The number of strings with $ 2$ zeros and $10$ ones is $\dbinom{12}{ 2}= 66$
- The number of strings with $ 3$ zeros and $ 9$ ones is $\dbinom{12}{ 3}=220$
- The number of strings with $ 4$ zeros and $ 8$ ones is $\dbinom{12}{ 4}=495$
- The number of strings with $ 6$ zeros and $ 6$ ones is $\dbinom{12}{ 6}=924$
- The number of strings with $12$ zeros and $ 0$ ones is $\dbinom{12}{12}=  1$

Comment: and what do they mean by integer multiple?

Comment: @guest11: The number of ones is divisible by the number of zeros.

Comment: then did you forget to add 1 from which is 12 C 0 = 1

Comment: @guest11: No. $12$ is not divisible by $0$!!!

Comment: hello Barak, I checked the answer with my friend and he got the full marks for this and the total was 1718 but when I added the total of your solution I got 1717. Besides, he has 1 which I was mentioning. However is there another method that we might get a diferent answer depends on the solution?

Comment: @barakmanos I think you are missing the case for 0 zeroes and 12 ones. That is the one that takes your total to 1718. So, following your logic, I think it should be 12 C 0 = 12!/(0!12!) = 1

Comment: oh thank you for catch that !!!! ^^

Comment: @GaurangTandon: $12$ is not an integer multiple (not divisible by) $0$.

Comment: @guest11: But $0$ **IS** a multiple of $12$. You're right, I'll correct the answer, thanks :)

Comment: @barakmanos Yes you are right I misread the question about that.

Comment: hello Barak but where's al the numbers comes from? like why "The number of strings with 6 zeros and 6 ones is"

Comment: @guest11: Please look at the first two comments here (your question and my answer).